# Tiva C PWM pin connected to counter and XOR gate changes pulse width

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, tm4c123g

I want a slow enough programmable clock for my circuit which I am generating using Tiva C PWM pins. Its a Tiva C 123GXL. The current frequency I have set is 200kHz and 50% high pulse (duty cycle).

When I connect the binary counter (A series of JK flip flops - IC 7473) everything works well, and clock division happens well and I can see 100kHz 50kHz etc. on the various flip flops.

But as soon as I connect the PWM to a XOR gate (IC 7486) also, the pulse width at the output of first flip flop keeps changing per cycle.

Any idea what is happening? Is two fanouts distorting the CLK input to the flip flop? In that case how do I use this generated clock in multiple places?

EDIT:

The Tiva C is being powered by a USB connected to my PC and the 7486 and 7473 have a DC supply of +5V-0V (yes, I have grounded both together)

EDIT2: My apologies, the problem is in output of the flip flop and not the PWM output. PWM output stays same.

Comment: @Tyler the Tiva C is being powered by a USB connected to my PC and the 7486 has a DC supply of +5-0 (yes, I have grounded both together). The high-level input voltage for both 7486 and 7473 is 2V so a 3.3V pulse should trigger them correctly.

Comment: What is the purpose of the XOR gate, and how is it wired? Do you have a power supply bypass capacitor across each IC? Can you show us a photo of your setup? 'scope traces of the signal?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Ahh I dont have access to a DSO anymore, I'll add them sometime later. Also do you know why the Low input current for 7486 is -1.5mA (from the datasheet). If its giving out current, that is a problem.

Comment: Standard TTL gates have an NPN Emitter input stage that sources about 1.1mA when pulled low (1.6mA max). If you think it's a problem then set the GPIO drive strength to 8mA, or switch to LSTTL or HCT logic!